# How do read multiDicts in python (flask)

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, multidimensional-array

I have a list of rows

```
[
    {'name': 'John', 'email': 'John@test.com'},
    {'name': 'Jenny', 'email': 'Jenny@yahoo.com'}
]
```

I am using ajax to send them from javascript. I am not sure how to read it in python/flask. I can see the data in request.form. When I try to access it, I am running into issues.

`request.form[0]` does not give me `{'name': 'John', 'email':'John@test.com'}`

```
@app.route('/listusers', methods=['POST'])
def do_listusers():
    for data in request.form:
        print(str(data))
        print(str(data['name']))
```

data itself is

```
[
    {'name': 'John', 'email': 'John@test.com'},
    {'name': 'Jenny', 'email': 'Jenny@yahoo.com'}
]
```

I was expecting

```
{'name': 'John', 'email': 'John@test.com'}
```

Also `data[0]` is not valid as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Send JSON data from Template to Flask using AJAX using POST request:**

- Set request header to content type JSON.
- `JSON.stringify` the data before sending to Flask.

**Receive JSON data in Flask:**

- Use `request.get_json()`. Details of this method can be found in [official documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.get_json).

I am showing an example of sending JSON data to Flask, processing in Flask and returning the processed data from Flask to template.

Initially the JSON data contains an array of objects:

```
[
      {"name": "John", "email": "John@test.com"},
      {"name": "Jenny", "email": "Jenny@yahoo.com"}
]
```

Suppose we need to modify this data to have an `id` attribute.

Folder structure:

```
├── app.py
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

def get_processed_data(data):
    for i,item in enumerate(data):
        data[i]["id"] = i
    return data

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        request_data = request.get_json()
        processed_data = get_processed_data(request_data)
        return jsonify(processed_data), 200
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

`index.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Post JSON data using AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>
    POST JSON data using AJAX
  </h2>
  <button id="send_data_btn">Send Data</button>
  <script>
  var send_data_btn = document.getElementById("send_data_btn");
  function postData() {
    var request_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/";
    var request_payload = [
      {"name": "John", "email": "John@test.com"},
      {"name": "Jenny", "email": "Jenny@yahoo.com"}
    ];
    var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr.open('POST', request_url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
        var processed_data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(processed_data);
      }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(request_payload));
  }
  send_data_btn.addEventListener("click", postData);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: JSON data POST request from template to Flask]

When user clicks on `Send Data` button, it sends the JSON data from template to Flask app. In Flask app, the data is processed and returns the processed data to template.

Comment: You guys are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You should parse data string received from ajax request to json using json.loads function.
Your code will be similar to this:

```
import json
data = request.form.getlist('data')
# data = ["{'name': 'John', 'email': 'John@test.com'}",
# "{'name': 'Jenny', 'email': 'Jenny@yahoo.com'}"]
for item in data:
   item_json = json.loads(item)
```

Please find this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-json/).